# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator - How to connect databse with wso2?

Tags: wso2

I have mysql database. When i trying to configure DataSource, im getting the bellow error.

> The data source URL is not accepted by any of the loaded drivers. CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

I have placed com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in components/lib folder

what am i missing?

Comment: Did you check this document?     https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/data_integration/rdbms-data-service/

Comment: Yes, but stil not working

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository} - The data source URL is not accepted by any of the loaded drivers. CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: The data source URL is not accepted by any of the loaded drivers. CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH is required

Comment: Can you paste your jdbc connection string?

Comment: Driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
| URL = jdbc:mysql://178.128.110.102:3306/cp2019?serverTimezone=UTC